# Better way to convert pandas column containing numbers stored as text to numbers

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've got an Excel file where the material group column contains both numbers (e.g.: 1120) and strings (8120M). In a different report (which is handled by a different team and I can't edit it) the same column is string only (number stored as text). In order to use pd.merge() or any Excel functions I have to convert the numbers in that file to numbers. Most of the merges are done based on that column, there's no workaround (the rest are based PO and vendor number fortunately)

This works, but seems really ham-fisted. The report itself is around ~15,000 lines monthly, so even the YTD rolling report won't go over 200k lines. Still, if there's a more elegant solution I'd like to know as my data won't always be this small.

```
raw["Matl Group"] = (
        raw["Matl Group"]
        .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
        .fillna(raw["Matl Group"])
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` without `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Matl Group': ['1120', '8120M']})
df['Matl Group'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Matl Group'], errors='coerce') \
                     .fillna(df['Matl Group'])
print(df)

# Output:
  Matl Group
0     1120.0
1      8120M
```

Alternatively, you can use `pd.factorize` to create a numeric value of `Matl Group`:

```
df['Matl Group Numeric'] = pd.factorize(df['Matl Group'])[0]
print(df)

# Output:
  Matl Group  Matl Group Numeric
0       1120                   0
1      8120M                   1
```